# Writing out a specific line of a list

Tags: c#, if-statement, file-io, console

I have a large file, and I took that file and divided it into 2 groups: A and B. Below is a sample of each line in the file:

```
 5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.
```

In a nutshell, I am writing a program that will look into both groups A and B, and if a line has "Savings found:" it will write out that line. Also if that file has a saving of 30% or greater, it will write out that line and put 1 asterisk in front, and if it has savings of 30% or greater and $500 or greater, it will write out 2 asterisks. For clarification, the 257.18 is the amount of savings that was found, and the percent next to that number is the percentage that has to be found.

This is the if statement that I have so far, I just need the code that has to go inside the if statement:

```
if (a.Any(item => item.Contains("Savings found:"))
{

}
```

I am new to c# and I have no idea how to make the console write the specific line of code that has these requirements. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `Any` would just tell you if the line contains that, just use a normal foreach over a and then do what you desire with each item

Comment: You are new to C# and you wrote a nice piece of `LINQ` statement. Strange!!!

Comment: Ok but how do I do the overall goal: to get the Console to write out those specific lines of code and have asterisks in the ones with requirements

Comment: @Rahul that took about 3 hours of research to find, and what the heck is LINQ?

Comment: @Rahul There have been several other questions posted within the past few days that have this exact same *example line* from `file` in it. I suspect he has been working on this several days, and using StackOverflow to answer simple questions.

Comment: `Linq`/`foreach` (to proceed each line) + `Regular expression` (to find out "Savings found:" with *amount* and *precentage*)

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping, but the main problem isn't really solved. I need the console to write out the lines and the asterisks. I have no idea how to do it and I could really use the help. Don't worry about the if/foreach statements just please help with the other part of the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we're helping out with a school program here.  There were several questions yesterday that dealt with almost the exact same issue and data.

In the mean time, since you want to iterate your result set to look for the exact savings, I would recommend the following, instead of using the "if". Using the "Where" query will do the same as the "Any", but will return a collection, instead of a boolean.  Going straight into the "foreach" will help save a step too.

```
var find = "Savings found:";

foreach(var line in a.Where(w => w.Contains(find))
{
  var subStr = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(find)+find.Length);
  var startIndex = subStr.IndexOf('(');
  var endIndex = subStr.IndexOf(')');

  var savings = double.Parse(subStr.SubString(0, startIndex-1).Trim());
  var percent = double.Parse(subStr.SubString(startIndex+1, endIndex-startIndex-2).Trim());

  Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", (percent >= 30) ? "*" : string.Empty,
                                 (percent >= 30 && savings >= 500) ? "*" : string.Empty,
                                 line);
}
```

From here you can parse the line data to find the savings and you can write out whatever data you need to.

Parsing the string is basically just breaking the string data into different parts to try and get the data you want. But since you're just looking for the percentage, check the code above for a further example

Comment: this is really awesome, except I have just one problem: when I ran this, it gave me:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero. 
I didn't think we had to specify a length?

Answer (score 1):

The Any method will just tell you whether any one of the items in your collection matches the provided criteria.

You can better loop the items with a Foreach:

```
a.ForEach(item => { if (item.Contains("Savings found:")) { Console.WriteLine(item); } });
```

This will check every item in a. If the item contains the string `Savings found:` it will print the item on the console.

Comment: It's a *partial solution*: you have to use *regular expression* to find out savings *amount* as well as *percentage* in order to add one or many asterics

Comment: @DmitryBychenko would you be willing to provide an example of the percentage using a regex? Ive been trying to figure this out for awhile and I am not getting any closer to a solution

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done much C# for a while but assuming you just want to write to the console, something like:

```
foreach (string myLine in A)
{
       if (myLine.Contains("Savings found:") == true)
       {
            Console.WriteLine(myLine);
       }
       if...(further code to deal with 30%+ savings, etc...)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("*" + myLine);
       }
       .....
       ...
}
```