# Fixing a System.FormatException

Tags: c#, debugging, formatexception

I am writing a code that will look at a group in a text file called a, and if a line in that code contains the phrase "Savings Found" it will write out that line, and if has 30% or more savings it will place an asterisk in front and if it contains 30% or more and has $500 or more savings, it will place two asterisks. Below I have a sample data, an example of what the console needs to look like, and the code I have thus far:

```
    string find = "Savings found:";
    foreach (var line in a.Where(w => w.Contains(find)))
       {
          var subStr = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(find) + find.Length);
          var startIndex = subStr.IndexOf('(');
          var endIndex = subStr.IndexOf(')');

          var savings = double.Parse(subStr.Substring(0, startIndex - 1).Trim());
          var percent = double.Parse(subStr.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 2).Trim());

          Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", (percent >= 30) ? "*" : string.Empty,

          (percent >= 30 && savings >= 500) ? "*" : string.Empty,
                                                        line);
         }
```

Sample data/example

```
* 5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.
```

The problem that I am having is I am getting a FormatException error, and I think I know what the problem is. The problem is that the value of subString is the 257.18 and everything after that. I don't want everything after it I just want the number. What can I do to get rid of that extra junk so it can compile?

This problem is similar to a previous question asked, however in that answer I get an ArgumentIndexOutOfBounds exception, tried to fix it, but did not go far in actually fixing the problem, hence the reasoning behind this question.

Comment: "So that it can compile?" This seems to be a runtime error, not a compiler error.

Comment: @ThomasWeller it is a runtime error. I apologize for the mistake. thank you for pointing it out I appreciate it

Comment: I guess you're including the `$` and `%` in the parse method which does not work.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you're right. Those, plus the extra stuff is in there, and all I want are the numbers so the program can run the way it is supposed to

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing out a specific line of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599777/writing-out-a-specific-line-of-a-list)

Comment: This is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599777/writing-out-a-specific-line-of-a-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623600/argumentindexoutofbounds-exception-string-length

Comment: This is either one poster with multiple accounts, or we've got students from the same class working on the same project.  There was another question with the same line of code yesterday (since deleted), though the issue was a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for that:

```
foreach(string line in a)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"Savings\s+found:\s*\$(?<savings>\d+\.\d+)\s*\(\s*(?<percent>\d+\.\d+)\s*%");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        decimal savings = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["savings"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        decimal percent = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["percent"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string prefix = string.Empty;
        if (percent >= 30)
        {
            if (savings >= 500)
                prefix = "**";
            else
                prefix = "*";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are able to reproduce the error. That's great! Reproduceable problems are typically easy to fix.

Assuming you have no other tools like OzCode or ReSharper, this would be the way of debugging and fixing it:

Once you know the line in which the error occurs, make the statement simpler. That is, break it down into smaller parts. In your case

```
var savings = double.Parse(subStr.Substring(0, startIndex - 1).Trim());
```

Does too many things, so you don't really know what the problem is. Split that into:

```
var savingsString = subStr.Substring(0, startIndex - 1).Trim();
var savings = double.Parse(savingsString);
```

Because then, during debugging, you can add a watch to `savingsString` and see that it is
[image: Watch windows in VS]

You can think about the fact why "$257.18" cannot be parsed and find counter measures to it. With the code before, you didn't even know the input which caused the problem.

Potential countermeasures:

- remove the dollar: `.Replace("$","")`
- start the substring later: `subStr.Substring(1, ...)`
- `savingsString = savingsString.Trim('$');` if you cannot be sure whether it is in the beginning or the end

From your program code, it seems you know all required methods, you just don't know how to debug.

Continue with this approach and you'll be able to fix all problems of your code and even future problems.

And: I can't recommend Regex. They are unreadable and nobody wants to maintain them.

Comment: I doubt that a mix of Find/Substring/Replace is more readable than regex.

Comment: I agree with @UlugbekUmirov, and youre suggesting he make a unit test? or test his code one unit at a time? because they are not the same thing.

Comment: @JasonPortnoy: I agree. The concept of unit tests might be too much for the OP. Remove that part.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you want the number and decimal values after "Savings found:"
regex should help. Theres probably a better way than this, but this should work.

```
 string find = "Savings found:";
    foreach (var line in a.Where(w => w.Contains(find)))
       {
          //line = 5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found."
          Regex regex = new Regex(@"Savings found:\s\$[0-9]*.[0-9]{2}\s*\([0-9]*.[0-9]{2} %\)");
          Match match = regex.Match(line);
          var savingsFoundSection = match.Value;

          MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(savingsFoundSection, @"[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}");
          String savingsString = matches[0].Value;
          String percentString = matches[1].Value;
          //savingString = "257.18"
          //precentString = "11.55"

          var savings = double.Parse(savingsString);
          var percent = double.Parse(percentString);

          Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", (percent >= 30) ? "*" : string.Empty,

          (percent >= 30 && savings >= 500) ? "*" : string.Empty,
                                                        line);
         }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When I run the debugger, the var savings line pops out an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Says Length cannot be less than 0

Comment: whoops, hold on one second

Comment: Still have a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, except this time it says Specified argument was out of range of valid values

Comment: This time tho the error is popping up on the savingsString line

Comment: Same problem in the savingString line. If it is easier, the savingsString value is reading 445.00, savignsFoundSection has "", and matches[0] has it threw an exception of type System.ArgumentoutOfRangeException